# How to say “Taking Japanese class has been fun” using 〜ものだ

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to say "Taking Japanese class has been [or was] fun" using ものだ.

But I don't think this is right:

> 日本語の授業を受けている楽していたものだ。

Comment: Yeah, it's not. What happened here 受けている楽していた?

Answer (score 7):

I see two big problems with your sentence:

1. In your sentence, 受けている doesn't relate in a natural way to what follows.
2. 楽{たの}しい is an adjective, but you're conjugating it as though it's the non-existent verb 楽{たの}す.  (Actually, because the kanji are the same, it looks like a form of 楽{らく}する, but I don't think that's what you intended.)

I think you could simplify it a little, connecting the two parts with 〜て:

> 日本語の授業を**受けていて楽しかった**（です）

Here I used the past form of 楽しい, which is 楽しかった.  I put です in because I imagined that you were talking to your teacher so politeness would be appropriate, but of course whether you want to be polite depends on context, so I put it in parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use ものだ/もんだ, I'd suggest

> 日本語の授業を受けるのは楽しいものだ(よ)。
>   日本語の授業を受けるのは楽しいもんだ(よ)。
>   日本語の授業を受けるのは楽しい(です)(よ)。